# Android Gridview - Not able to select image inside Griditem with Android-Box remote

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am creating a android app in which i have list of channels(items) in a Custom `GridView`.
I have a favorite icon associated with each channel to add them in favorites list.
On click of this favorite icon the channel gets added to the Favorites List of channels.

When i use a android box remote i am not able to select the `ImageView` for favorite.
Instead the whole `GridItem` gets selected.
The single grid item is a `LinearLayout` which mainly has two `ImageView`s in it.

View code for a single grid-item of the gridview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="false" 
    android:clickable="true"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/channelLogo"
        android:layout_width="75dip"
        android:layout_height="75dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:focusable="false" 
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>


        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/channelName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:focusable="false" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center" 
            />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/channelStatus"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:focusable="false" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"   
            />

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/addToFavourite"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false" 
            android:contentDescription="Add to favourites"
            android:src="@drawable/addfavorites"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

Code for my grid adapter where i handle the click of the `ImageView` (for adding a channel to favorite).

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private int resourceId;
    private ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private ArrayList<Category> categoryList = new ArrayList<Category>();
    private int size;
    private Integer[] mThumbIds;
    private ViewGroup gridGroup;
    private static final String PREFS_FAVOURITES = "favourites";

    public GridAdapter(MainActivity c, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Item> data, int gsize) {
        mContext = c;
        resourceId = layoutResourceId;
        itemList = data;        
        size = gsize;
        mThumbIds = new Integer[gsize];
        for(int i=0;i<mThumbIds.length;i++) {
            mThumbIds[i] = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return mThumbIds[arg0];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageUrl;
        TextView channelNameTxt;
        TextView channelStatusTxt;
        ImageView imgFavourite;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String contextClass = mContext.getClass().toString();
        ViewHolder holder;
        gridGroup = parent;
        View grid = null;
        if(convertView==null){
            grid = new View(mContext);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
            if (contextClass.contains("MainActivity") || contextClass.contains("FavoriteActivity")) {
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
            }
        }else{
            grid = (View)convertView;
            return grid;
        }

        if (contextClass.contains("MainActivity")) {
            if (position < itemList.size()) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.channelNameTxt  = (TextView) grid
                        .findViewById(R.id.channelName);
                String channelName = itemList.get(position).getChannelName().replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
                holder.channelNameTxt.setText(channelName);
                holder.channelStatusTxt = (TextView) grid
                        .findViewById(R.id.channelStatus);
                holder.channelStatusTxt
                        .setText(itemList.get(position).getStatus());
                if(itemList.get(position).getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("Online")) {
                    holder.channelStatusTxt.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);  
                } else if(itemList.get(position).getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("Offline")) {
                    holder.channelStatusTxt.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }

                holder.imageUrl = null;
                try {
                    holder.imageUrl = (ImageView) grid
                            .findViewById(R.id.channelLogo);
                    holder.imageUrl.setTag(itemList.get(position).getImageUrl());
                    new DownloadImagesTask().execute(holder.imageUrl);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.toString());
                }
                final Item info = itemList.get(position); 

                holder.imgFavourite = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.addToFavourite);

                holder.imgFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         //GridView gridview1;
                        if(mContext.getClass().toString().contains("MainActivity")) {
                            GridView gv = (GridView)gridGroup;
                            final int position = gv.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Position is :" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FAVOURITES, 0);
                            String favourites = settings.getString("favourites", "");
                            Item clicked_item = itemList.get(position);
                            String sep1 = "<sep1>";
                            String sep = "<sep>";
                            String favourite = clicked_item.getChannelUrl()+sep1+clicked_item.getChannelName()+sep1+clicked_item.getStatus()+sep1+"Favorite"+sep1+clicked_item.getImageUrl()+sep;
                            favourite = favourite.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
                            if(!favourites.contains(favourite))
                                favourites = favourites+favourite;
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                            editor.putString("favourites", favourites);
                            editor.commit();
                        }
                    }
                });

                grid.setTag(holder);

            }
        } 
           return grid;
    }
```

This works fine on a android phone.